How to speed up autovacuum
Autovacuum execution takes a long time on my postgres9.4 instance, and my question is:

Can I improve the speed of autovacuum by dropping the index? If I terminate the vacuum during the process, will its results take effect, as I may need to terminate the current vacuum before the drop index.
Is there any other way to speed up autovacuum.

I've increased maintenance_work_mem, set vacuum_cost_limit to a higher value and set vacuum_cost_deplay to 0.
Any suggestion or help would by appriciated!

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You're about 5 releases beyond EOL - consider an upgrade. Considerable work has gone into this!

@Vérace Thank you for the suggestion. We are planning an upgrade, but it may take us several months. I am concerned that the slow speed of the current vacuum may soon cause transaction ID wraparound.

Changing vacuum_cost_delay doesn't do anything for autovacuum, unless autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay is set to -1 (which is not the default).

Thanks, decrease autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay did help.

The best things to speed up autovacuum are

Upgrade.
PostgreSQL 9.6 has introduced substantial performance improvements for VACUUM, and later releases have improved that even more.

Increase autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit or reduce autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay.
Setting autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay to 0 will make autovacuum go as fast as it can.

Crank up maintenance_work_mem to 1GB.


Yes, dropping an index will speed up autovacuum.
Increasing max_parallel_maintenance_workers will only help with manual VACUUM, as autovacuum doesn't use parallelism yet.
If you interrupt autovacuum, it may have already done some work that the next run won't have to repeat, but it could also be that you lose everything.

Thanks for your answer, we will arrange an upgrade.

I am running version 9.4，can I upgrade directly to version 15 or 16, or do I need to upgrade one major version at a time?

You should be able to upgrade directly.

@LaurenzAlbe Everywhere else on the Internet I read that autovacuum does not vacuum indexes in parallel, regardless of max_parallel_maintenance_workers. Nothing related in the recent Postgres 17 release notes either. Can you clarify?

@rafbm Would you rather trust the PostgreSQL source code or "everywhere else on the internet"?

@LaurenzAlbe Thanks for pointing to that page. I looked up “auto” and the only occurrence I found does confirm parallelism isn’t supported for autovacuum. I admit I’m not fluent in PostgreSQL source code, but that one comment is very clear. :)

@rafbm I love it! That's the power of open source - you don't have to argue, you can just read up in the source. I have fixed my answer.
